# SSRS - Boolean Parameter to pick max date

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to create a Boolean parameter that would perform the following:

- If the user indicates True, the report will return rows with the most recent date, rather than show duplicates.
- If left False, the report runs as normal, pulling each row and leaving the duplicates.

SSRS doesn't appear to allow me to say something like =IIF(Parameters!MaxDate=1, Fields!MaxCreatedDate, Nothing). Does anyone have an idea of how I could accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest transferring the logic to the code that actually gets the data.

Comment: Can you explain how I would do that? I'm fairly new to SSRS.

Comment: Should be something like `=IIF(Parameters!MaxDate.Value = True, Fields!MaxCreatedDate.Value, Nothing)`

Comment: I've tried that but I receive an error when trying to preview my report saying that "Fields cannot be used in query parameter expressions".

Comment: Hi check this link maybe could help you http://kirkbarrett.wordpress.com/2013/11/29/filtering-datasets-using-a-boolean-report-parameter-to-determine-in-value-set/

Comment: The solution described in that article won't work for the same reason as I described above: I can't use fields in report parameter expressions.